# Как можно реализвать проверку введённого?

Tags: python

Не могу придумать как можно проверить пароль на наличие заглавных символов и спец символов.
Условия, которым должен отвечать пароль: минимум 8 символов, 2 русских, 2 латинских, 2 цифры и 2 знака препинания. Причем 2 символа, должны быть заглавными.
Я смог только слелать проверку на длину. Подскажите пожалуйста.